# Extracting information of JSON file

Tags: python, json

I got results through `results = requests.get(url).json()`
results look like this:

```
{'type': 'FeatureCollection',  'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties':
 {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}},  'features': [{'type': 'Feature',   
 'properties': {'kode': '0101',
     'navn': 'København',
     'region_kode': '1084.0',
     'region_navn': 'Hovedstaden'},    'bbox': [12.453042062098154,
     55.612994971371606,
     12.734252598475942,
     55.732491190632494]}]}
```

with `results['features']`, I am getting this

```
[{'type': 'Feature',   'properties': {'kode': '0101',    'navn':
 'København',    'region_kode': '1084.0',    'region_navn':
 'Hovedstaden'},   'bbox': [12.453042062098154,
    55.612994971371606,
    12.734252598475942,
    55.732491190632494]}]
```

I want to get the information in `navn`
and I tried all combination of

```
results['features']['properties']['navn']
results['features']['navn']
results['features']['properties']
```

they all show the same error message that: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

apparently, `results['features']` is a list with a length of 1.

how can I get to `navn` information?

I want to make several calls as you can imagine.

Comment: That's because `results['features']` is a list type with one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `results['features']`object is a list, try `results['features'][0]['properties']['navn']`

Now you select the first element in the list (0), the dictionary, and from that dictionary you select the 'navn' key. The result is the value of 'navn'

Note that python lists are between [] and items are seperated by a comma and python dictionaries are between {} and consists of key, value pairs seperated by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You should try accessing the first element of the `list` in `result['features']`, i.e.:

```
results['features'][0]['properties']['navn']
```

---

Full code:

```
results = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}}, 'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
'properties': {'kode': '0101', 'navn': 'København', 'region_kode': '1084.0', 'region_navn': 'Hovedstaden'}, 'bbox': [12.453042062098154, 55.612994971371606, 12.734252598475942, 55.732491190632494]}]}
print(results['features'][0]['properties']['navn'])
# København
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
results['features'][0]['properties']['navn']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code below:

```
results['features'][0]['properties']['navn']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = {'type': 'FeatureCollection', 'crs': {'type': 'name', 'properties': {'name': 'EPSG:4326'}},
       'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
                     'properties': {'kode': '0101', 'navn': 'København', 'region_kode': '1084.0',
                                    'region_navn': 'Hovedstaden'},
                     'bbox': [12.453042062098154, 55.612994971371606, 12.734252598475942, 55.732491190632494]}]}

navn = results['features'][0]['properties']['navn']
print(navn)
```

You got error because  inside features there is one list. So, you can not get list with the help of  str index and to get the properties inside the features you need to write `[0]` and the list will gone  and you can  get the value.